# Property 'id' not found in Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

How can I get around this warning in PhpStorm?

```text
Property 'id' not found in Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
```

for

```php
auth()->user()->id
```

*Note, that this question relates to PhpStorm not Laravel. The id exists and Laravel doesn't show the warning. The IDE does.*

Comment: Have you used `auth` middleware for the route?

Comment: yes, but I don't think this is related to the warning

Comment: 1) Does `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` **interface** has the `id` property there? I do not think so. 2) What does `user()` returns in `auth()->user()`? (the PHP type / PHPDoc -- what PhpStorm can read during static analysis without actually executing the code?). Is it `\App\User` (concrete implementation) or the above interface? You see, if it's an interface (as it should) .. then you CAN code so the it uses not the default `\App\User` model but your custom `\App\MyUser` .. where you MAY NOT have the `id` attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phpstorm does not know about the object. You can add something like this to your user model:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 */

class User ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with `Auth::user()->id` and you can show this warning, you should to do a `dd(auth()->user())` and you can show that are happening. Maybe your user it´s not logged and for this Laravel show this warning

Comment: Note, that this question relates to phpstrom not laravel. The id exists and laravel doesn't show the warning. The IDE does

Comment: @JanBoehmer maybe need extension to recognize laravel sintaxis...